# flock vs lockf on Linux

Tags: c, linux, locking

If `lockf` is used with a 0 offset, what are differences between `flock` and `lockf` when used in exclusive mode, if any?

I'm asking because I'm reading code that conditionally compiles in either of these 2 functions based on platform and I want to understand possible reasons why.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The practical difference between `flock()` and `lockf()` is in the semantics (behaviour with respect to closing and passing), applicability over NFS and other shared filesystems, and whether the advisory locks are visible to other processes using `fcntl()` locks or not.

The library you're using simply has logic to pick the desired semantics based on the current platform.

If the semantics (behaviour over descriptor passing, forking, etc.) is acceptable, you should prefer `lockf()`/`fcntl()` locks over `flock()` locks in Linux, simply because the former works on NFS etc. filesystems, whereas the latter does not. (On BSDs and Mac OS X, I believe you need to explicitly use `fcntl()`, instead.)

---

In Linux, [`lockf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/lockf) is just a wrapper around [`fcntl()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html), while [`flock()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) locks are separate (and will only work on local filesystems, not on e.g. NFS mounts on kernels prior to 2.6.12). That is, one process can have an advisory exclusive `flock()` lock on a file, while another process has an advisory exclusive `fcntl()` lock on that same file. Both are advisory locks, but they do not interact.

On [Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/lockf.3.html) and [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=flock&sektion=2), `lockf()`/`flock()`/`fcntl()` locks all interact, although developers are recommended to use only one of the interfaces in an application. However, only `fcntl()` locks work on [NFS mounts](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mount_nfs&sektion=8) (and, obviously, only if both NFS client and server have been configured to support record locks, which is surprisingly rare in e.g. web hosting environments; a huge cause of headaches for some web (framework) developers).

POSIX does not explicitly specify how `lockf()`/`flock()`/`fcntl()` locks should interact, and there have been differences in the past. Now, the situation has calmed down a bit, and one can *approximately* say that

1. `fcntl()` locks are the most reliable

   Across architectures, they have the best chance of working right on e.g. shared filesystems -- NFS and CIFS mounts, for example.
2. Most often, `lockf()` is implemented as "shorthand" for `fcntl()`

   The other alternative, as "shorthand" for `flock()`, is possible, but nowadays rare.
3. `fcntl()` and `flock()` have different semantics wrt. inheritance and automatic releases

   `fcntl()` locks are preserved across an `exec()`, but not inherited across a `fork()`. The locks are released when the owning process closes *any* descriptor referring to the same file.

   In Linux, FreeBSD, and MAc OS X, `flock()` locks are coupled with the open file descriptor: passing the descriptor also passes the lock. (The man pages state that *"the lock is on the file, not on the file descriptor"*. This is not a contradiction. It just means that the lock *applies* to the file. It is still coupled to the descriptor, in such a way that duplicating the descriptor also passes the same lock, too.) Therefore, it is possible that multiple processes have the same exclusive advisory `flock()` lock on the same file at the same time, if they obtained the descriptor from the originator after the `flock()` call.

File locking is surprisingly complicated issue. I have personally had best results by simply sticking to `fcntl()` locking. The semantics wrt. `fcntl()` locks are not the easiest to work with, and in certain cases can be frankly infuriating; it's just that I've found it to yield the best -- most reliable, most portable, least surprising -- results.

Comment: Addendum to comment above: Linux 2.6.12 was released on 18 June 2005, so even at the time of the answer flock() did work on NFS.

Comment: @Akilan: Which part? Do not confuse `flock()` with `lockf()`; it is horrible to comment like that without pointing out exactly what is wrong. It is like saying that you have made an error, without pointing to the error. It is not only unhelpful, but makes the tone very smug and unfriendly. I believe you yourself have just confused `lockf()` and `flock()` in the NOTES section. As to NFS and `flock()` on kernels prior to 2.6.12, yes, that does warrant a note, thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry it wasn't very clear. I'm indeed talking about the NFS.

Comment: @Akilan: No, that was clear. You said "the answer is no longer true", but did not point out **how**, or which part. Without further details, I must disagree, because other than mentioning the kernel version, I do not see how my answer differs from the man page at all.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for the conditional compilation is that neither of the two functions is available on every platform.

Comment: That was my initial thought, checking revealed that they were both supported on the platforms. It may not have been the case historically though, so this seems to be the front-runner.