# Why is File::FcntlLock's l_type always "F_UNLCK" even if the file is locked?

Tags: linux, perl, flock, fcntl

The Perl subroutine below uses `File::FcntlLock` to check if a file is locked.

Why does it return `0` and print `/tmp/test.pid is unlocked.` even if the file is locked?

```perl
sub getPidOwningLock {
    my $filename = shift;

    my $fs = new File::FcntlLock;
    $fs->l_type( F_WRLCK );
    $fs->l_whence( SEEK_SET );
    $fs->l_start( 0 );
    $fs->l_len( 0 );

    my $fd;
    if (!open($fd, '+<', $filename)) {
        print "Could not open $filename\n";
        return -1;
    }

    if (!$fs->lock($fd, F_GETLK)) {
        print "Could not get lock information on $filename, error: $fs->error\n";
        close($fd);
        return -1;
    }

    close($fd);

    if ($fs->l_type() == F_UNLCK) {
        print "$filename is unlocked.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    return $fs->l_pid();
}
```

The file is locked as follows (lock.sh):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
(
    flock -n 200
    while true; do sleep 1; done
) 200>/tmp/test.pid
```

The file is indeed locked:

```sh
~$ ./lock.sh &
[2] 16803
~$ lsof /tmp/test.pid
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
bash    26002 admin  200w   REG    8,5        0 584649 test.pid
sleep   26432 admin  200w   REG    8,5        0 584649 test.pid
```

Comment: I don't know, but `flock($fd,6)` shows that the file is locked.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::FcntlLock#F_GETLK) say you get with `F_GETLK`? "With `F_GETLK` the `lock()` method determines if and which process currently is holding the lock. If there's no other lock the `l_type` property will be set to `F_UNLCK`."

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Correct. I believe you misread my question. The Perl code is not supposed to lock.

Comment: But why wouldn't it lock? `flock` is not the same as `fcntl`. See [man(2) flock](http://man.he.net/man2/flock): "Since  kernel  2.0,  flock() is implemented as a system call in its own right rather than being emulated in the GNU C  library  as  a  call  to fcntl(2).   This  yields  true  BSD  semantics: there is no interaction between the types of lock placed by flock() and fcntl(2)..."

Comment: See also: [What is the difference between locking with `fcntl` and `flock`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29611352/2404501).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: I think you should publish that as an answer.

Comment: @Borodin I felt like I might be misunderstanding what the OP wanted, so I was waiting for them to clarify. But now Wumpus Q. Wumbley has written a nice, thorough answer.

Comment: Related: [On the Brokenness of File Locking](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/locking.html)

Comment: I was torn between writing the answer and asking for the underlying reason for the question. If the purpose was to synchronize some perl scripts and the shell script was just a test, then the easier answer is: quit using a shell script to test this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fcntl` and `flock` locks are invisible to each other.

This is a big problem for your use case because the `flock` utility that you're using in your shell script depends on `flock` semantics: the shell script runs a `flock` child process, which locks an inherited file descriptor and then exits. The shell keeps that file descriptor open (because the redirection is on a whole sequence of commands) until it wants to release the lock.

That plan can't work with `fcntl` because `fcntl` locks are not shared among processes. If there was a utility identical to `flock` but using `fcntl`, the lock would be released too early (as soon as the child process exits).

For coordination of a file lock between a perl process and a shell script, some options you can consider are:

- port the shell script to `zsh` and use the `zsystem flock` builtin from the `zsh/system` module (note: in the documentation it claims to use `fcntl` in spite of its name being `flock`)
- rewrite the shell script in perl
- just use flock in the perl script (give up byte range locking and the "get locker PID" feature - but you can emulate that on Linux by reading `/proc/locks`)
- write your own `fcntl` utility in C for use in the shell script (the usage pattern will be different - the shell script will have to background it and then kill it later to unlock - and it will need some way to tell the parent process when it has obtained or failed to obtain the lock, which will be hard because it's happening asynchronously now... maybe use the *coprocess* feature that some shells have).
- run a small perl script from the shell script to do the locking (will need the same background treatment that a dedicated `fcntl` utility would need)

For more information on features of the different kinds of locks, see [What is the difference between locking with `fcntl` and `flock`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29611352/2404501).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I decided to rewrite the shell script in Perl/`File::FcntlLock`, as it was only used for testing.