# flock lock is lost after the second check

Tags: c++, c, linux, macos, locking

I am using `flock` to prevent concurrent access to a shared resource. It works fine the first time I check the lock, but the second time I check the lock, I am able to successfully obtain it despite the fact that lock is stil being held by another process.

I am using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main(void) {

 printf("App started:\n");

 int fd = open("test.lock", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666); // open or create   lockfile
 //check open success...
 int rc = flock(fd, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB); // grab exclusive lock, fail if   can't obtain.
 if (rc)
 {
    printf("Failed .. lock is already held\n");
    if(EWOULDBLOCK == errno)
    {
      printf("errno said, that we would block\n");
    }
    return 0;
 }
 else
 {
   printf("Lock obtained\n");
 }

 printf("Press ENTER...\n");
 getc(stdin);
 return 0;
}
```

Platform: OSX 10.10.

If I run the program in two separate terminal windows, I get the following output:

First window - the app acquires the lock and waits for key to be pressed

> App started:
>   Lock obtained
>   Press ENTER...

Second terminal window  first run - application sucesfully finds out, that the lock is already held by someone else

> App started:
>   Failed .. lock is already held
>   errno said, that we would block

Second terminal window second run - application obtains the lock despite the fact that first instance is already holding it

> App started:
>   Lock obtained
>   Press ENTER...

It as if testing  for lock would also release it...

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: This looks like OS X related problem. The code works without problem on 14.04 32 bit. 
Matra

Comment: This appears to be C code. Any **valid** reason you added the C++ tag?

Comment: Check for errors. And release the lock!

Comment: this code block: `       printf("Failed .. lock is already held\n");

        if(EWOULDBLOCK == errno)
        {
            printf("errno said, that we would block\n");
        }` can be simplified to one line: `perrof( 'flock failed");`   as that would print the enclosed text plus the appropriate system error message.  Then no need for the statement: `#include <errno.h>`

Comment: I ran the code in a terminal window, and let it sit waiting for a user keystroke.  Then in a second terminal window I ran the code over and over and over.  it always output: `App started:
Failed .. lock is already held
errno said, that we would block`   I.E. on my system, ubuntu linux 14.04, it always works correctly

Comment: Thanks, I also get it working on Ubuntu.l It looks like this is an OS X specific problem. I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem on OS X was that program was run from network mounted directory (windows share). Locks do not work reliably on NFS. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22411531/174638 for details.